# Vertices not showing in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

For some reason, some of the vertices of my mesh are not being displayed in edit mode:

[image]

This is my mesh (it is all a single mesh).  I am in edit mode with vertex selection enabled.  You can see some of the vertices displayed on the hair and on the seams of the clothing.  However, most of the clothing's vertices are not there.  If I go into edge or face select mode, I can select the edges and faces of the blank areas, but am unable to move them.

The clothing parts were originally created using a solidify modifier that was then applied to make a solid region.  Not sure if that is a factor.

How do I get the vertices to display over the entire mesh?

Comment: are you talking about the UV Editor or about the 3D view? Maybe you have hidden your vertices?

Comment: That was it.  I had accidentally hidden my vertices in 3D view.  Thanks.